# android import system source code into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I did the search and saw some similar title but I don't believe my question is aleardy there. If there is, please tell me and feel free to mark this as a duplicate.

I'm trying to import the `Sources for Android SDK` (which is listed on the SDK Manager) into  Eclipse. I don't intend to compile or run it, but instead for learning propose. I just think it's more convenient to use Eclipse's functionality such as "Open declaration" accross multiple java files than reading through the source code in a plain text editor. Is it possible? I've already downloaded the sources and see an `android-17` folder in my `sdk/sources/`. What to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Open the navigation pane and right click on your android.jar > go to Properties > Java source attachment > External Location and add the sources folder there as pictured :

[image]

Now if you ctrl click on an android class/method in one of your classes you will jump to the class file for that class/method *inside the java editor*